Soft bodies for car tires
How would you go about using soft bodies for the tire tread of a car?
I can simulate the tread by itself squishing and deforming easily, however, I haven't figured out how to attach it to a tire rim (which is not supposed to squish) and then attach that to an axle/body of the car.

Video example (soft body tire treads are parented to the tire rim, with goal enabled)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3SWlJNjkgc
Your help is appreciated.

Side note, use blend-exchange.com for Blend file sharing on this site, whenever you can.

My issue was related to a tutorial that I was following in which they set the "bending" value to 2. I got the treads to behave correctly by lowering this value. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhYrHxxbZUc&t=62s
So basically.

parent the treads to the rim.
Assign the inner tread to a vertex group.
use the vertex group as the goal in the soft body settings
set default strength to 1.
check mark edges.
play with the bend value + other settings.

However, I am dealing with another issue where the treads want to slide towards the left while touching the ground. This seems to be especially so if the treads don't have much geometry.

You should post the second issue as a separate question. I’m glad you found the solution to this one!

I believe the way to do this is to create vertex groups of the beads of the tires (I.e. the part where they touch the rim), and then in the soft body physics, set those groups as goal weighting groups with 100% spring stiffness strength and maximum weight. With the tire objects parented to the non-soft body wheel aka rim objects, that should give you what you’re looking for.

where can "pin groups" be found in the soft body physics?

if you mean the vertex group within the goal setting, I have tried that but it doesn't seem to pin the rim area.

Sorry, yes I do. Did you turn the spring stiffness and the max influence all the way up?

I have. the tire stays in place but looses its soft body characteristics. as if its pinning the whole tread, even though the vertex group only includes the vertices where the treads meets the rim.

You seem to be getting the treads and the sidewall mixed up.
